# Calculating explicit integral with Fubini

Tags: integration, measure-theory, trigonometry, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Hey I am trying to solve following integral, but i dont have any idea how to proceed.

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{1} \sin(y^2) dydx$

I have tried to solve it with substitution, but i am missing a term, namely sth like $ay$.

Trying to use Lebesgue integral with Fubini and transformation I got $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\sin(y^2)\cdot \chi_{[0,1]\times [x,1]} d\mathcal{L^2}(x,y)$, but I have still the same problem... how to proceed?

I also tried to use the series of sine $\sin(y^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} y^{4n+2}$, but then this series is not monotone so i can not use monotone convergence so that does not really help, or do I miss sth?

Does anyone have a hint for me?

Comment: Try to draw the area you are integrating over and see how the borders of integration change when you interchange the integrals.

Answer (score 1):

I explain my comment in more detail here:
We integrate over the set $\{(x,y)|0\leq x \leq 1, x\leq y\leq 1\}=\{(x,y)|0\leq y\leq 1,0\leq x\leq y\}$. So when interchanging the integrals we obtain $\int_0^1 \int_0^y \sin(y^2)dx dy=\int_0^1 y\sin(y^2)dy$. Now using the substitution $t=y^2, dt=2y dy$ we obtain $\int_0^1 y\sin(t)\frac{dt}{2y}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \sin(t) dt=\frac{-cos(1)+cos(0)}{2}$.